# How to get the property name set to false value

Tags: powershell

I am still new to powershell. I have been trying to get only the Nic properties that have been set to false.

So when I run:
`Get-NetAdapter | fl *` it brings up all the results for each property of the Nic. I only want to see the properties that have been set to false.

I have tried `Get-NetAdapter | where {$_ -like $false}` and `Get-NetAdapter | where {$_ -like "*false*"}`. Have also tried sorting but also cant get working

Much Appreciated

Comment: `Get-NetAdapter | % { $_.PSObject.Properties } | ? Value -eq $false | % Name`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
(Get-NetAdapter).PSObject.Properties | Where-Object Value -eq $false | Select-Object Name
```

If you want the results as string array instead of an object array, use `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`

Note: This only works as intended if you have a single NetAdapter. The code in the comment from PetSerAl will give you all properties from all adapters, but you don't see from which adapter.

If you want to test multiple adapters, you should write an additional loop for example like this

```
$adapters = Get-NetAdapter

foreach ($adapter in $adapters)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green "$($adapter.Name)"
    $adapter.PSObject.Properties | Where-Object Value -eq $false | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name
    Write-Host ""
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Just what I was looking for. :-)

Comment: @bsunkel: Would you mind marking this as accepted answer then, so the other users don't see this question as open?